# Can I bake a quiche with a flaky crust?

Tags: pastry, quiche

I want to bake a chard quiche. Normally, I would use short pastry for the crust, but I want to practice my flaky pastry skills. Still, I plan to bake it in the normal quiche form. It is white glazed ceramic, slow to heat up, slow to release heat, and doesn't get as hot as metal.

Will this be OK? Can I expect the flaky crust to turn out nice, or do I risk it to become soggy/non-crispy/whatever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flaky pie pastry works beautifully for quiche.  You can improve the texture with two techniques.  The first is "blind-baking," or a partial pre-bake to toast the crust lightly.  The other is to brush a wash of egg white onto the crust before blind-baking.

Answer (score 1):

A ceramic pie dish should be fine, even superior.

The only thing you'd change is if you're blind baking the crust (some do, some don't) before filling it, you'd want to take it out of the oven sooner because the pan will retain heat.

EDITED TO ADD: Flaky pastry, in my experience, is the normal crust for a quiche.